# How to send an email in C# with gmail template/signature

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I know how to send an email with C# using the System.Net.Mail library. I can send it with gmail, which is the provider I want.

Yet when I send an email the nice Gmail signature / template isn't added. I need this to be added because it will be business emails that will be send from the application, so it needs to look professional.

I have already tried to use the gmail API but I am not able to send an email with that... There are almost no tutorials or forums about Gmail API for C# and no code previews.

So I need to know if it is possible to send an email with a signature that is already specified on the Gmail account. If this is possible, how can I do it?

If you know that this is not possible, but should be with the Gmail API. Could you tell me how to send an email with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about creating a html page, have all the signature etc set up in that page and send it as email. You can tokenize text that needs to be dynamic. There are plenty of library who can handle token etc. It should render fine then

Comment: Ok, but how do I make sure that the html is put at the end of the email?

Comment: The whole email content will be the HTML file. So your email content, signature etc all goes in that html file. Then you can parse the email and send out using standard .net library. This way you will have all the controls on how your email looks like

Comment: I got it kinda working now, I found the HTML code for the signature on Gmail. I copied it into my program as a string and put it at the end of the email and set the mail.IsBodyHtml to true. Only now he thinks everything is HTML so enters don't work anymore.. If I have that page, I can import it into the program and put my custom text into it? It needs to be different every time

Comment: Yes you can change the content as your like. When I said token, those token are the values which can be replaced. Something like this Dear [Name] hence [Name] is the token you would want to replace before sending your email. Before sending the email you can use some HTML parse library and replace those token values with whatever you like

Comment: Thank you I will do some google searches!

Comment: I succeeded, thank you for your answers. I did it a bit different but it still works. Thank you!

Comment: Okay in this case I will write an answer on what we have discussed here then you can mark it as answer?

Comment: yeah okay man! haha ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a html page for your email content. For content of the email that is need to be dynamic you can use tokens. Like for name in the email that needs to be changed you can use a token in the html like Dear [Name]. Before sending the email you need to find html file parser (there are plenty out there) and replace values of token to what you want them to be.